# segmentaion fault в старых образах debian

Tags: debian, docker

в старых образах *debian gnu/linux* с docker-hub-а, запускаемых на (например) текущем стабильном выпуске *buster*, происходит "segmentation fault" при запуске (например) программы *bash*:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti debian:6 sh
# bash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
# exit
$ docker run --rm -ti debian:7 sh
# bash
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
# exit
```

как это исправить средствами docker-а?

Comment: продублировал на [en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57807835/4827341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как это исправить средствами docker-а?

средствами программы *docker* — никак.

требуется передать параметр `vsyscall=emulate` программе *linux* при загрузке.

это можно сделать в файле `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, но чтобы изменения не потерялись при обновлении пакета *grub*, стоит добавить этот параметр в переменную `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, описанную в файле `/etc/default/grub`, после чего выполнить:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

---

ссылки:

- [Segmentation fault when running bash in a CentOS 6 container #34301](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34301)
- [Normal running now fails, for CentOS 6.x images, on Debian testing, after upgrading Linux kernel from 4.9 to 4.11 #58](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/58#issuecomment-315150740)